# Reaction Of Carbonic Acid With NaCl

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism, water, reaction-control, salt

I was just wondering if it was possible for anyone to **specify what reaction conditions are required for the reaction between $\ce{H2CO3}$ (Carbonic Acid) and $\ce{NaCl}$ (Sodium chloride)?**

Does this reaction happen naturally, or is an input of energy or catalyst required?

Will this reaction still proceed if the $\ce{NaCl}$ is in an aqueous solution i.e. dissolved in water? **As both substances exist in the sea, does this reaction occur in the ocean as well?**

Comment: For the record, $\ce{H2CO3}$ does not exist as a separate entity. It is actually a solution of carbon dioxide in water maintaining equilibrium.

Comment: Also, refer to these papers: [1](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0016703706020527), [2](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja01222a037).

Comment: Keeping aside this question is very close to the one posted by you earlier (https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/135748/collecting-the-products-of-a-reaction-before-they-themselves-react) -- and actually, the answer as well -- you could compute the Gibbs / free reaction enthalpy of this reaction postulated, too.  This would give you a sense if _energetically speaking_ the reaction were favourable, or not.  (There are some reactions, like diamond to graphite, which are favourable at RT but face a kinetic barrier this high that they don't occur at significant rate, though, too.)

Answer (score -1):

$\ce{H2CO3}$ and $\ce{NaCl}$ do not react.

The sodium chloride provides a surface with high friction which allows the $\ce{CO2}$ to transform into a gas. The same thing happens with mentos and fizzy drinks.

One might say that the sodium chloride is serving as a catalyst for the transformation of $\ce{H2CO3}$ into $\ce{H+(aq)}$ and $\ce{CO2(g)}$.

Comment: The answers on the remote link are s...uboptimal, but your content here looks good. I remove the link and format your answer. It would help a lot, if you would then provide a better link.

Comment: No, the question was not correctly answered now or previously! The answer is an outline of the Solway Process centering on the introduction of NH3 to the mix of aqueous NaCl and CO2. Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solvay_process .